# Calculating a Wald CI for a mean of model parameters, or reparametrise model?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, incidence-rate-ratio

I am working with a PI who strongly wants to compare his results to a paper I find methodically confusing, if simple.

The goal is to calculate weekly rates and adjusted rate ratios from a multi-year dataset, and compare weeks between years. So my rate ratios would be for Week 1 2020 vs Week 1 2021 and so on, as estimated model parameters.

The paper presents an annual rate ratio with CI as well (so comparing all 2020 to all 2021) which as far as I can tell is the arithmetical mean of weekly RRs and a CI for that value (no info on how they calculated it; I am assuming using the pooled variance of the parameters and assuming the estimates are distributed normally).

I think the most valid way to move forward is with both weekly models and a separate annual (matched weekly events case-control conditionally) regression, in order for my CI to be closer to what readers think it is (a CI for the parameter, rather than the mean of many parameter estimates). Am I correct, or am I missing something allowing the first paper to present their results as an "annual" rate in this way?